# What do you call what remains to be paid of invoice?

Tags: finance

There is an invoice in a computer system. It has the "total sum" and the "paid sum" associated with it. How do you call "what remains yet to be paid" on this one invoice? And which sign, plus or minus should be displayed along this number?

Comment: Perhaps *Balance*, *remaining sum*?

Comment: _Outstanding balance_. More of an [ELU](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) question

Comment: (this is ELU. you linked ELL.)

Comment: I think you meant to ask *what* to call it, not *how*. "*How* do you call an invoice?" asks something like "How do you make them pay?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term (in the US, at least) is **balance due.**

No sign needs to be displayed, since *balance due* expresses that money is owed by the customer. If you owed the customer, there would be a *credit.*

https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/balance+due